# How iterate with cim.featureTable.fieldDescriptions?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, valueerror, cartographic-information-model

I have the next code:

```
#Importar librerías necesarias
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

#Obtiene el Mapa activo
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
current_map = aprx.activeMap
capas_list = current_map.listLayers()

#Create a empty list
layers_list = []

#Realiza la busqueda de layers en el mapa activo y sus respectivos fields.
print("Map: {0} Visible Field in Layers".format(current_map.name))
for layer in capas_list:
    if layer.isFeatureLayer:
        # Get the layer's CIM definition
        n = len(capas_list)
        field_position = {}
        cim = layer.getDefinition('V2')
        #Create a empty list
        field_list_lyr = []
        #Iterar a través de todos los campos y si son visibles ejecuta
        for i, field in enumerate(cim.featureTable.fieldDescriptions):
            if field.visible == True:
                #Get field name
                field_layer = field.fieldName
                #Add field to list
                field_list_lyr.append(field_layer)
                #field_position[capas_list.index(field_layer)] = field
            else:
                field_position[n] = field
                n =+ 1
                
        print (layer, field_list_lyr)    
        data_layer = str(layer).split("\\")
        data_layer.append(",".join(field_list_lyr))
        layers_list.append(data_layer)
```

How can I get it to return fields from all layers and not just the first one? Attached result

[image]

I have tried with the `#field_position[capas_list.index(field_layer)] = field`
but it throws me the following error:

```
Map: Búsqueda Visible Field in Tables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [3]:
Line 28:    field_position_t[tablas_list.index(field_table)] = field

ValueError: 'OBJECTID' is not in list
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please add the error messages as text, not picture.

Comment: Have you verified that the field visibility in say the `Piscina` layer are all turned on? Are all layers shapefiles/file geodatabases or are they web services? Add that information to your question.

Comment: Yes, I verified this info and all turned on. The layers are shapefiles.

Comment: According to Esri, what you are seeing is expected behavior.  See the accepted answer to [cim_lyr.featureTable.fieldDescriptions returns an empty list](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/cim-lyr-featuretable-fielddescriptions-returns-an/td-p/1046116).  In light of this behavior, I think the answer is don't rely on the CIM model when other ArcPy functionality exists, like in Hornbydd answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your code and use of the CIM object and I too could not get the code to run properly. I tried it in the jupyter notebook and Python console and it failed, which leads me to believe there is a bug, unless its some subtle flaw in the code I can't see? That said you do not need to use CIM to query field properties, the standard arcpy class fieldInfo can give you what you need, below is a minimum code example:

```py
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
current_map = aprx.activeMap
layers_in_map = current_map.listLayers()

layers_list = []  #Create a empty list

# Read fields
print("Map: {0} Visible Fields in Layers".format(current_map.name))
for layer in layers_in_map:
    print("processing " + layer.name)

    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)  # Create a describe object

    # If a feature layer, continue
    if desc.dataType == "FeatureLayer":
            
        field_info = desc.fieldInfo  # Create a fieldinfo object
                    
        field_list_lyr = list()  # Create an empty list

        # Step over field descriptions
        for index in range(0, field_info.count):
            if field_info.getVisible(index) == "VISIBLE":
                #Get field name
                fieldname = field_info.getFieldName(index)
                
                #Add field to list
                field_list_lyr.append(fieldname)
                    
        print("data=" + layer.name + str(field_list_lyr))
```

Comment: I had created it that way initially but it doesn't keep the order of the fields (given the case that it has been modified in the map), in such a way that I had to unify the two codes to make it functional. Thanks a lot anyway.